# Making sense of Polymer's core-layout-grid arrangement data structure

Tags: layout, polymer

The [HTML from the core-layout-grid-example](https://github.com/Polymer/core-layout-grid/blob/master/demo.html) includes:

```
<core-layout-grid nodes="{{nodes}}" layout="{{layout}}"></core-layout-grid>
<panel id="toolbar">toolbar (click to rotate)</panel>
<panel id="sidebar">sidebar</panel>
<panel id="workspace">workspace</panel>
<panel id="outputToolbar">otherbar</panel>
<panel id="output">
  output
  <h2>Documentation</h2>
  <h1>Verbiage</h1>
  <p>In backbone record integer LED amplified internet protocol a extension reflective. 
  Array kilohertz LED. Wavelength extension patch supporting wave an by prompt.</p>
</panel>
```

The [demo example](https://github.com/Polymer/core-layout-grid/blob/master/demo.html) includes this code:

```
Polymer('grid-test', {
  arrangements: [[
    [1, 1, 1, 1],
    [2, 3, 3, 4],
    [2, 3, 3, 5]
  ], [
    [4, 3, 2],
    [5, 3, 2],
    [5, 1, 1]
  ], [
    [1, 1],
    [2, 3],
    [4, 3]
  ]],

  outputLayout: 0,

  ready: function() {
    this.outputLayoutChanged();
  },

  outputLayoutChanged: function() {
    this.layout = this.arrangements[this.outputLayout];
  },

  toggleLayout: function() {
    this.outputLayout = (this.outputLayout + 1) % this.arrangements.length;
  },

  rotate: function() {
    this.toggleLayout();
  }
});
```

How are we supposed to interpret the matrices shown above?

Answer (score 0):

According to Dominic from https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/polymer-dev/pFYsYExD2VY

> The layout property is basically a picture of how you want the layout done. For example:

```
[[2, 2, 2],
 [1, 3, 3],
 [1, 3, 3]]
```

> 1 means the first child, 2 the second, etc. You can kind of imagine the edges of the picture are sticky and the elements stretch with them. Easiest thing is to play with it, it'll make sense.

Update: The code above has multiple matrices just as a demo so the user can rotate through various layouts to see the effect.